# WSO2 ESB - How to use resource's property as a URL parameter in In Sequence

Tags: esb, wso2-esb

I'm try to RESTful to RESTful mapping. My end point is `http://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk`

And I'm map it to 
`http://localhost:8080/get_weather/uk/London`

This is my source view of resource,

```
<api name="API_1" context="get_weather" hostname="http://localhost" port="8080">
    <resource method="GET" uri-template="/{p1}/{p2}/">
        <inSequence>
            <log level="custom">
                <property name="param1" expression="get-property('uri.var.p1')" />
                <property name="param2" expression="get-property('uri.var.p2')" />
            </log>
            <send>
                <endpoint key="http://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q{param2},{param1}" />
            </send>
        </inSequence>
    </resource>
</api>
```

Finally i will use to `curl` to make the request

```
curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -X GET http://localhost:8080/get_weather/uk/London
```

How to use logged parameters in `endpoint`?

Answer (score 0):

Try with something like this :

```
<send>
  <endpoint>
    <http method="GET" uri-template="http://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={uri.var.p2},{uri.var.p1}"/>
  </endpoint>
</send>
```